# MySQL compare and update if different

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables `users` and `cached_users`. Table `users` is updated and that's my active table. `cached_users` is my second table and I update that table every 15-20 min.

> TABLE USERS

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+------------------+
| id            | name          | username      | email            |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+------------------+
| 1             | Johne Doe     | john.doe      | johndoe@mail.com | 
+---------------+---------------+---------------+------------------+
```

> TABLE CACHED_USERS

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+------------------+
| user_id       | name          | username      | email            |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+------------------+
| 1             | Johne Doe     | john.doe      | johndoe@mail.com |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+------------------+
```

> MY QUESTIOS IS:

How can I check the differences between the two tables and update if something is changed? So I have multiple rows and loop trough all `users` rows and find matching `cached_users` row and update if needed. I have more column in `cached_users` table so I can't do "DELETE/INSERT" method. I need an SQL statement for this action. If you need more information, feel free to ask.

Comment: Which field are you specifically interested in and which fields keeps on changing?

Comment: @SMA I want to update result from table "users" into table "chaced_users", so if name is differente update only name.

Comment: Is ID a key column(column used for comparing data between tables) here? or something else?

Comment: yes ID is a key column for comparing

Answer (score 0):

select * from users union select * from CACHED_USERS

if the count is same as users then there is no updation has occured if differs means

select p.id from (select * from users union select * from CACHED_USERS) p group by p.id having count(*)>1

id exist more than one means those records need to be updated.

Comment: I have differente number of columns in tables and I don't need only new rows but a existing one if change is happened.